# How can I hide/protect my client-side HTML/JS code?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a simple **game** using HTML5, but not using canvas, as the interface/graphics are really basic and it would be quite hard for me to do it using canvas as I have no experience with it.

As I already know (and some answers to other questions like this explained), it's not possible to hide the client-side code, as the browser must read it, and obfuscating it or using iframes won't really protect it. But as it is a game, almost all the logic is on the client-side, so it would be terrible to be exposed.

Overall, is any method that I can use to protect my client-side code? Or should I learn how to use canvas or a HTML5 game engine?

Comment: Sorry, but obfuscation is the best you can do.

Comment: Please look into minifying and uglyfying your code to make it unreadable, you unfortunately can't hide it.

Comment: maybe use a unity plugin in web https://unity3d.com/webplayer

Comment: debugger jammer's are also handy

Comment: @osdamv But I can't use HTML/JS on Unity, can I?

Comment: no, unity doesn't support  html/js however is one standard in the industry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obfuscation really is the best you can do... Take a look at http://www.jsfuck.com/# as Obfuscation goes its about as good as it gets as long as file size isn't a concern

```
let what = 1; alert(what);
```

becomes 26330 chars!

Comment: Yeah, it looks like an amazing obfuscation option if I stick with Javascript to build my game.

Comment: The problem with jsfuck is that it's a very imbalanced obfuscation technique. If you take a closer look at code obfuscation metrics, you'll see that jsfuck excels in one metric (potency) but fails at another (resilience) - meaning that a human will have a hard time de-obfuscating the resulting code but an automated tool will do it very easily. Don't really recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

Client-side code *cannot* be hidden from the end-user. You can make use of a combination of [minification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) and [obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) to help *deter* users from reading your code, but you cannot outright *prevent* a user from doing so.

If you are concerned about users viewing sensitive source-code such as passwords, you can store this information server-side, and then load it into your JavaScript with an [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) call.